# What exactly is a FLOP?

Tags: terminology, computer-science, floating-point

I know that is a "FLoating-point Operation" but,what exactly mean this!? Can anyone make me a mathematical example of a FLOP?

For example, is $\sqrt{2}$ a FLOP?

Comment: The Green Lantern movie was a FLOP. With a capital F.

Comment: @AsafKaragila and a capital LOP it seems :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No a floating point operation is an operation like $+$ $-$ $\cdot$ or $/$, where the numbers and the result are both floating point numbers.

Comment: So, $\frac{1.5}{2.33}=0.644$ is a FLOP right?

Comment: calculating it takes a flop yes

Comment: What do you mean with the words "it takes a flop"?

Comment: as i know flop it is a measurement of the complexity, it is not a real calculation

Comment: Ahh, I have understand, one FLOP is a elementary operation, in the forms mentioned above, is correct?

Comment: yeah exactly that is it

Answer (score 2):

Googling : How many FLOPs does a sqrt() take?

Here a few answers :
*[faq](http://folding.stanford.edu/Spanish/FAQ-flops)
*[flop counting](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/976/flop-counting-for-library-functions)

HTH